# How can I select a mirror than the one apt-get chose for me?

Tags: apt, mirrors

In a way my question is an inversion of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror).

I'm trying to do `sudo apt-get install jags` from the terminal, and it selects mirrors close to me, but then it says "Not Found".

I'd like to select a mirror that isn't close to me, but which actually works. Can I do that?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364919/how-can-i-restore-a-country-specific-apt-get-update-mirror) seems to point at a solution, but it won't work for me because I can only access the terminal.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/586601/158442?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have terminal, you have to manually edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.  There's no other way unfortunately to do this.

You'll have to replace the domain names in the `sources.list` of the current mirror with whatever mirror you wish to use.  The standard archives tend to be the most updated source with updated packages, however it may not be the closest to you (`archive.ubuntu.com`).

However, a `404` error suggests that there's a newer package version or such available; make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` first, then try and install the package, to **rule out** the mirror you're using as the actual problem.

Comment: How do you find the domain names one can use to update `/etc/apt/sources.list`? I'm doing that in a Docker container and right now my `sources.list` contains these
`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main`,
`deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main`,
`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main`